# Pyinstaller can't find target architecture when building bootloader

Tags: arm, pyinstaller, nanopi

Let me explain what I did first. As most people do, I first used pip to install pyinstaller.

```
pip3 install pyinstaller
```

Everything seemed fine. It exited with "finished successfully" message. I then tested it with a simply python code. It went all the way to the end and then showed the following message.
[image]

Having no clue at all, I decided to uninstall pyinstaller and download the source to build on the machine. After building bootloader, it exited with "finished successfully" as well but with another warning message.
[image]

I ignored it and continued to install pyinstaller. It also ended with successfully message. When I tested it, the same "not include a pre-compiled bootloader" error showed.

Here is what I get from /proc/cpuinfo. It's NanoPi Neo with 4 cores.
[image]

I'm using the latest image from FriendlyARM, which was released on June this year.
[image]

Okay, the architecture was not recognized, and I don't think "thumb" is the correct architecture, either. Does anyone have idea how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the output of ``platform.machine()`` & ``platform.system()`` on your machine? (do it with ``import platform`` on interactive terminal)

Comment: @gfdsweds platform.machine() ==> armv7l, platform.system() ==> Linux